# encodeURIComponent ignored by Expo Router push method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, url, routes, expo

```js
const {name} = foo; // "foo 2%"
const encodedName = encodeURIComponent(name); // "foo%20%25"
router.push(`/recipe?&name=${encodedName})}`
```

this just literally does not work and I have no idea why. If I console.log `encodedName`, I can see it is properly encoded, but when you navigate to the route and inspect the params, it is not.

```
/recipe.jsx

const {name} = useLocalSearchParams() // "foo 2%" <- this has to be a bug
```

it crashes the page because expo router thinks it's a broken URI component when it tries to decode it. I'm losing my mind, I've been debugging for 3 hours straight. I straight up think this is a bug in expo router.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: No, I think this is an unreported bug in Expo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883629/3865079

The parentheses was the issue for me. And it is indeed a bug.

This is how I solved it:

```js
const params = {
  ...
  details: JSON.stringify(details).replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, 'EXPO_ROUTER_FIX[$1]'),
};

router.push({
  pathname: '/<path>',
  params,
});
```

And then I reversed it like so:

```js
const details = JSON.parse(params.details.replace(/EXPO_ROUTER_FIX\[(.*?)\]/g, '($1)'))
```

This way the params are not empty when calling `useLocalSearchParams` in the receiving component and we only replace the parentheses we changed.